# No Error Found During Build and Error Found in the Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC, not pro at this. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I have a project and I cannot find an error in my code. Neither can the build.

There was no error during build and the project loaded just fine. However, there is an error on one of the pages. In fact, later on I found many small errors on the pages that none was caught by the build. So I cannot help but feel like something is missing.

My question is, I am trying to locate where the errors are, it would be great if there was a debug tool I can use to locate them, or is there something I need to load or use, since there aren't any errors found during Build?

Thanks!!!

Comment: And the code in question is?

Comment: Hi, I assume there are many errors, I am not sure where. I am trying to see if there is a tool I can install to find errors for me, because right now I can't find where the error exists, and the build doesn't seem to find it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the "MvcBuildViews" in your project, then you can see the errors during the build, if there are any errors including errors in the view pages.

**1)** Right click on your project, then select "Unload Project"

**2)** Right click on your project again, select "Edit yourproject.csproj"

**3)** find "MvcBuildViews" tag

**4)** Change the value in MvcBuildViews tag like below:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

**5)** Right click on your project again, select "Reload Project"

follow above process, you'll get the error message when you build solution and there is an error in view page.

Hope it helps.